# What were Hagrid's duties as Gamekeeper?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

He is not shown as having a major role in defining a young witch/wizard's education, nor is there any mention in the books or movies about what he did before he became a professor (as Gamekeeper/Keeper of the Keys).

What exactly were Hagrid's duties as Gamekeeper? What else were his duties?

Comment: Growing pumpkins? bringing in Christmas trees? hunting bad creatures in the forbidden forest? bringing babies to Dumbledore? We see him do quite a few stuff.

Comment: @MBEllis, sure. But which one of these are his 'duties' and not something he did because he wanted to is the question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hogwarts gamekeeper had many duties, including:

- Looking after the school's keys.

> "True, I haven't introduced meself. Rubeus Hagrid, Keeper of Keys and Grounds at Hogwarts."

- Escorting first year students on the boats to the castle.

> Hagrid, of course, was still fighting his way across the lake with the first years

- Tending to the gardens at Hogwarts.

> In the small vegetable patch behind Hagrid's house

- performing "special tasks" for the Headmaster and Professors at the      school.

> Fer Dumbledore. Hogwarts business." Hagrid drew himself up proudly. "He usually gets me ter do important stuff fer him."

- Looking after magical beasts on the school grounds.

> "Warm up, I think," said Madame Maxime. "But ze 'orses -"
>
> "Our Care of Magical Creatures teacher will be delighted to take care
> of them,"

- Tending to matters in the Forbidden Forest.

> There's a unicorn in there bin hurt badly by summat. This is the second time in a week. I found one dead last Wednesday. We're gonna try an' find the poor thing.

- Bringing the twelve Christmas trees into the Great Hall during December.

> they found a large fir tree blocking the corridor ahead. Two enormous feet sticking out at the bottom and a loud puffing sound told them that Hagrid was behind it.

- Defrosting the school brooms during winter.

> Hagrid could be seen from the upstairs windows defrosting broomsticks on the Quidditch field

- Making the pumpkins for the Hallowe'en feast.

> In the small vegetable patch behind Hagrid's house were a dozen of the largest pumpkins Harry had ever seen. Each was the size of a large boulder.

Comment: While "Looking after magical beasts on the school grounds." may well be a duty of the Gamekeeper, the quote from the Goblet of Fire doesn't match, as in this case Hagrid acts not as Gamekeper or Keeper of the Keys but as the teacher for Care of Magical Creatures, which he even doesn't become before that book.